# Visual Studio Code doesn't start in Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, visual-studio-code

I had been using VSC in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS for some time until it refused to start since recently. Ubuntu Software shows it's up to date but with a warning ([see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziBPI.png)). I can try to remove and reinstall, but I might have several files unsaved and I don't want to lose them by doing so. Any ideas to bring VSC back?

Comment: what is the output if you try to run `code` from the terminal?

Comment: No output with the command.

Answer (score 0):

You've installed it via the Snap Store.
Run `snap run code` from a terminal and see the command's output for hints.

Comment: It returns nothing.